# Putting Coffeescript Underscore.js and Backbone.js all together

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

**TLDR;** http://jsfiddle.net/squarism/zaVrE/

I'm new to Backbone.js and Underscore.js (Underscore I believe is included with Backbone).  I'm using this within a rails app but that bit of it doesn't/shouldn't matter.  I'm following the Railscast two part episodes on backbone.  I'm trying to grok underscore, backbone, coffeescript, debugging and everyone's documentation.  Adding to the confusion is differences between the Underscore API and the coffeescript version.

For example: I have an array of User objects as 'entries'.  Each have a winner attribute.  So this will work:

```
# why does this return everyone?
non_winners = @select(entries) ->
  @get('winner') == false
```

So there's a lot going on here.  The @select is from underscore.  The @get is from backbone.  And all of it is coffeescript.  Translating this to a JS debug line is a bit crazy.  Eventually though I did figure out the javascript outside of backbone to test this with.  My problem is the docs:

The docs say:

```
filter_.filter(list, iterator, [context]) Alias: select
```

I don't know how to read this.  I just called @select which I thought equated to .select() but I didn't give it an iterator.  In Javascript on the browser console, it returns an array only with Objects where winner is false.  In my app, if I console.log(non_winners) it gives me back everyone but console.log(non_winners.length) matches what I'd expect (ie: if I have one winner, it's 1).  This disparity is really confusing while I'm learning.

```
entries = [
  { name: 'Joe', winner: false },
  { name: 'Bob', winner: false },
  { name: 'Henry', winner: true }
]

# here's an example from my app
#non_winners = @select (entries) ->
#  @get('winner') == false

# here's an example from the API
#evens = _.filter [1..6], (num) -> num % 2 is 0

# here's something that works
non_winners = _.select entries, (entry) ->
  entry.winner is true
```

I find a few things confusing:

1. How do people actually debug this crazy combination.  Coffeescript, Underscore, Backbone, oh my!  Until I understand everything, I'd like to play with it.  JSfiddle (below) is nice but is there any hope of using a browser console?
2. How do you translate this @select() business (@ is coffeescript's self alias right, which points to the Backbone collection?) to underscore's _.select() api docs?  The order of the argument is different.
3. In the above example (and in the fiddle below), only one person is returned.  But in my app, all people are returned.
4. I can get one person to be returned in the fiddle but the syntax is different from the examples in the railscast (#323).
5. The code that works in the fiddle still really doesn't match the underscore API docs.  I'd like to learn how to read the underscore docs (learn to fish vs single fish etc).

You can see this in action: 
http://jsfiddle.net/squarism/zaVrE/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite clear from the fiddle what your problem is in your actual code. I think the main issue here is `@get('winner')` which is equivalent to `this.get('winner')`. You're calling a collection method instead of the entry method. `@` is simply a substitute for `this` (or `this.` in case of functions). Your code should be

```
non_winners = @select (entry) ->
  entry.get('winner') == false
```

`_` is just an object with a bunch of methods (including `select`). The Backbone.js collection objects happen to incorporate Underscore methods.

As far as debugging goes, the vast majority of the time it's trivial to map the JS in the browser to your CoffeeScript code. Sometimes the JS output isn't what you expect because of misaligned indentation or lack of brackets. That's easy to debug too - just look at the JS output.

Underscore.js and Backbone.js are simply JS libraries, so you can check out (or debug into) their code. It's quite clean and straightforward.

Comment: Ah.  I think you nailed it.  For some reason I thought that only this.get() would work and the entry instance variable wouldn't have .get() on it.  Thank you very much for the debugging advice.